# Quick Clarification Question about Time Complexity in CLRS

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics

I'm reading about the Hiring Problem in "Introduction to Algorithms" and read

> Interviewing has a low cost, say $c_i$, whereas hiring is expensive, costing $c_h$. Letting $m$ be the number of people hired, the total cost associated with this algorithm is $O(c_in+c_hm)$.

For clarification, this is the algorithm being referred to

```
HIRE-ASSISTANT(n)
    best = 0 // candidate 0 is a least-qualified dummy candidate 
    for i = 1 to n
    interview candidate i
    if candidate i is better than candidate best
        best = i
        hire candidate i
```

My question is, why does the book say the total cost is $O(c_in+c_hm)$ and not $\Theta(c_in+c_hm)$? For any input, since we must iterate over all $n$ candidates and given that $m$ are hired, couldn't we also say that the asymptotic lower bound is $\Omega(c_in+c_hm)$ therefore saying the cost for any input is $\Theta(c_in+c_hm)$?

Comment: This kind of question has been answered on this site, I believe. Here is the gist of the answer. Yes, it is correct to use either one of , Ω and Θ. However, people are more concerned about the upper bound of the worst case, which is easier to find, discuss and check in general. So, although Θ tells more,  is used much more consistently.